# Jquery Accordion Multiple Level Navigation

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am new to jquery. I am working on the jquery navigation for so many days, it works fine now, but i want to add more feature to it.

I have three level nested accordion navigation, and i want to let the user know which section they are on by apply background color to it, now i am only able to put background color to the last level they are on, how can i also apply different background color to the parent level.

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h3><a>Link One - First Level</a></h3>
    <div class="accordionSecond">      
        <h6><a href="#">Second Level</a></h6>
        <div class="accordionLink"> 
        <a href="1.html">1.html</a>
        <a href="2.html">2.html</a>
        <a href="3.html">3.html</a>
        <a href="4.html">4.html</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <h3><a>Link Two - First Level</a></h3>
    <div class="accordionSecond">      
        <h6><a href="#">Second Level</a></h6>
        <div class="accordionLink"> 
        <a href="1.html">1.html</a>
        <a href="2.html">2.html</a>
        <a href="3.html">3.html</a>
        <a href="4.html">4.html</a>
        </div>
    </div>    

</div>
```

here is the css line to apply the background color to the level they are on

```
.accordionSecond .activeLink { background: #ccc;  color:#000!important; }
```

jquery header code are here

```
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#accordion").accordion( {active: true,  collapsible: true, header: "h3", autoHeight: false, navigation: true, event: 'mouseup'}); 
    $(".accordionSecond").accordion( {active: true,  collapsible: true, header: "h6", autoHeight: false, navigation: true,event: 'mouseup'});
  });
  </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
     var path = location.pathname;
      jQuery("a[href$='" + path + "']").addClass("activeLink");
});
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hi take a look at the [click](http://api.jquery.com/click/) api which demonstrates also adding a class (lets say you added an 'active' class to the header you clicked) and the kind of behaviour your requesting. Obviously you will have to expand on this demo but there should be lots of example of adding and removing classes online.

Comment: i tried to add class, it will add class to all header once you click on one. i don't think this method working.

Comment: edit your question with the new code you tried at a guess it seems like your not selecting `this` element